# Image under static navigation bar not working

Tags: html, css

Check: [www.trillie.nl](http://www.trillie.nl)

You see when you scroll that the image goes over the nav bar instead of under it, like the rest of the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `z-index:9999;`   your problem is solved

```
#navigation {
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #000000;
    color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    height: 35px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;   // here is 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is use higher `z-index` to the `#navbar` than image so it will always above image like for navigation bar `z-index:5` and for image `z-index:4`.